# Paypal create payment-tokens API return 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using my paypal sandbox, and I am trying to use v2/vault/payment-tokens API to tokenize a credit card

Url:https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/vault/payment-tokens
Method: POST

RequestBody(fake credit card that sandbox generated):

```
{
    "source": {
        "card": {
            "number": "40320382525xxxx",
            "expiry": "2022-11"        
            }
    }
}
```

I can make sure that my sandbox have full scopes, my access token is right.

Below is the response:

```
{
    "name": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id": "15c1b3e9d8161",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "UNKNOWN_BUSINESS_ERROR",
            "description": "There was an issue while processing your request."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/vault/v2/#error-UNKNOWN_BUSINESS_ERROR",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does any one meet the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Will you have permissions to use /v2/vault/payment-tokens in live mode? This API shouldn't be integrated without guidance from PayPal

Try using a test credit card from https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/testing-go-live/node

Comment: Thanks, I tried with those test cards, and it went through.